# Android AOSP: The package with keyboard related code: What is key_preview_backing

Tags: android, keyboard, android-source, ime, latin

I customising the android open source project code dealing with the keyboard area. I saw the key_preview_backing in the inputView.xml file with the height of 0dp.

What actually key_preview_backing for?